# Como guardar un array en laravel

Tags: laravel, ajax, array

buen dia

mi problema es el siguiente tengo un input dinamico el cual tiene un boton que al presionarlo me crea otro input y haci cuantas veces sea necesario pero no puedo guardarlo en mi base de datos con laravel

**input:**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo[]"> <input type="button" class="btb btn-prymary btn-xs" id="add_field" value="adicionar">
```

investigando se que el name debe ir en [] para que guarde multiples datos estos datos los envio por ajax y en el controlador va esto

**controlador:**

```
    public function savepesos (Request $request){


     if($pesos=$request->get('campo')){
         foreach ($pesos as $peso) {
             
                pesos::create([
                    'peso_producto' => $peso['campo']
                ]);
         }
     }
```

**y el modelo**

```
    class pesos extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $table='TABLA_PESO_PRODUCTO'; 


     protected $fillable = ['peso_producto','codigo_formulario'];
}
```

en conclucion como puedo guardar ese input dinamico en mi base de datos con un solo click

Comment: Entonces...no guarda? Sale error? Y porque tienes el `request` en un `if`?

Comment: no guarda la verdad fue un tutorial que vi :(  alguna otra forma de guardar el input dinamico ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Aclaración**

- Cuando se obtiene un valor "multiple" con `[]`, lo que en verdad se obtendra sera un array agrupado por el nombre, en tu caso la variable agrupar seria `campo` por lo que tus datos serian asi (Puedes comprobarlo haciendo un `dd(request->all())`

```
"campo" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "sdsad"
    1 => "asdas"
    2 => "dad"
    3 => "11111"
  ]
```

**Problemas**

- En si, no deberias declarar y comparar al mismo tiempo que haces una condicion, por lo que `if($pesos=$request->get('campo'))` estaria mal. De esto asumo que lo metistes en la condicion para evaluar si esta obteniendo `campo` o no. Para esto se puede usar `$request->has()` ya que devuelve un booleano para hacer tu condicion
- Estas obtiendo la variable `campo` al hacer `$request->get('campo')` por lo que en tu `foreach` => `$peso['campo']`, no es necesario obtenerlo denuevo

**Solucion**

- Basicamente agregar el `request->has`(si quieres) y quitale `campo` a `$peso['campo']`

```
if ( $request->has('campo') ) {
    foreach ( $request->get('campo') as $peso ) {
        pesos::create([
            'peso_producto' => $peso
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Referencia**

- [request->has](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present)

Comment: gracias muy util tu ayuda funciona bien :)

Comment: Excelente, pero si por lo menos son dos inputs q van a la misma tabla con columna diferente como será la secuencia de la lógica?